# get the number of JSON object element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can get the number of elements in this JSON?

```js
gettingTheLocalStorageData = {
  "sortable2": {
    "content": "example_panel_2",
    "columns": "3",
    "panel-size": "large",
    "childs": {
      "item-1-sortable2": {
        "header": "Feeds 1 ",
        "body": ""
      },
      "item-2-sortable2": {
        "header": "Feeds 2",
        "body": ""
      },
      "item-3-sortable2": {
        "header": "Feeds 3",
        "body": ""
      },
      "item-4-sortable2": {
        "header": "Feeds 4",
        "body": ""
      },
      "item-5-sortable2": {
        "header": "Feeds 5",
        "body": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "sortable3": {
    "content": "example_panel_3",
    "columns": "3",
    "panel-size": "large",
    "childs": {
      "item-0-sortable3": {
        "header": "Feeds 1 ",
        "body": ""
      },
      "item-1-sortable3": {
        "header": "Feeds 2",
        "body": ""
      },
      "item-2-sortable3": {
        "header": "Feeds 3",
        "body": ""
      },
      "item-3-sortable3": {
        "header": "Feeds 4",
        "body": ""
      },
      "item-4-sortable3": {
        "header": "Feeds 5",
        "body": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should return 2 items (`sortable2`, `sortable3`), but it is returning `659`. The couple steps I have tried are:

```
console.log(gettingTheLocalStorageData .length); // = 659
```

and

```
console.log(Object.keys(gettingTheLocalStorageData).length); // = 659
```

any possible solutions?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gopYQ.jpg what im getting back

Comment: To be slightly pedantic, that's actually just an object - not an array, nor JSON (JSON is a string). That said, your second attempt seems fishy to me. `console.log(Object.keys(getLocalStoragedata).length);` would most certainly return `2`. **EDIT:** I just tried it myself, and as expected, it returns `2`.

Comment: These are objects, not arrays; if you want to count the number of keys in the object use Object.keys (as @TylerRoper points out, that line should return 2 (you seem to be using a different variable name there, though; "gettingTheLocalStorageData" instead of "getLocalStoragedata"? Perhaps that's the issue?)

Comment: This is what i get back when i run it: https://imgur.com/a/yGteda7

Comment: @Anish As Daniel noted, your variable name does not match in the example above. If you actually run the code you've included in your question, and only that code (`console.log(Object.keys(getLocalStoragedata).length);`), it returns `2`. Perhaps your issue is somewhere else, or you're simply using the wrong variable name, but without more information, we can't really help you solve a problem that we (nor your question) can reproduce.

Comment: @TylerRoper it was a copying error. I fixed the naming. All of it should be named gettingTheLocalStorageData  sorry about that. if you look a the image i still get the same result

Comment: @Anish If you run the code that is in your question, the result is `2`, therefore we can't really help you debug. Take a look; I've literally  copy + pasted the code right from your question: https://jsfiddle.net/Lprsoxn2/

Comment: @TylerRoper Thanks a lot for help. I guess i'll rewrite and try it again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parse JSON first,

```
let parsed = JSON.parse(getLocalStoragedata)
console.log(Object.keys(parsed).length); // 2
```

Comment: `getLocalStoragedata` is not JSON, it's an object (it's already parsed) I believe OP misspoke in saying so. That said, your second line seems to be the proper solution. OP said they'd already tried this but I have my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(getLocalStoragedata).length
```

Comment: OP states in the question that they tried `Object.keys()` already. That said, I'm not going to downvote your answer because I think it's correct, and OP has made a misstep somewhere.

Comment: So you are doing something wrong. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/wjmkht4a/

Comment: @clayton.carmo Thanks a lot for help. I will rewrite and try it again

Answer (score 0):

I just had to parse it for it work.

added

```
 gettingTheLocalStorageData = JSON.parse(gettingTheLocalStorageData);
```

and now it return the correct number

same as @Deda

Comment: Two things: First off, this means that the value of `gettingTheLocalStorageData` is not what you've provided in your question. Second, Deda submitted that answer an hour ago - you should accept it.

Comment: @TylerRoper how do i accept an accept it? I don't see the option too. I looked and couldn't find it that why i posted the reply

Comment: To the left of his answer, there should be a checkmark icon. Clicking this will accept the answer. For more information, check this out: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)